# Series de X aXis opuesto no se muestran en el "Navigator"

Tags: highcharts

Tengo un problema.

Tengo un gráfico con 6 series, 3 corresponden al eje X inferior y 3 al superior. El problema es que las series superiores no se muestran en el componente "Navigator", y cuando muevo el rango en este, el gráfico se rompe y el eje superior ya no coincide con el inferior. Aquí la evidencia:

http://jsfiddle.net/6gqbj8sk/9/

Además, me gustaría que los 2 ejes queden alineados de entrada, cosa que no esta sucediendo. Es como que para la misma fecha y hora, los datos se encuentran desfasados.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: puedo preguntar cual es la razón de separar las series en 2 axis?

Comment: Necesito mostrar 2 series que corresponden a 2 momentos de tiempo diferentes, apra poder comparar punto por punto. Por eso la serie de arriba de del 23/10 al 24/10 y la de abajo del 24/10 al 25/10.

Comment: ese tipo de comparación yo lo haría con highchart normal, no con stockchart

Comment: Pero necesito que el navigator este disponible.

Comment: podría saber por que razón? es que creo que podrías poner esta comparación en un highchart y agrupar los datos por rangos de fechas en vez de hacer esto en un tipo de gráfico basado en línea de tiempo que bueno se rige estrictamente a una linea de tiempo, tener dos no se si sea posible

Comment: Y pero como haria luego para poder hacer zoom en diferentes niveles de tiempo?

Comment: categorizando, la idea es ver esta comparación de otra forma, te dejo un ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/jhbgt2Ld/

Comment: Es muy buena tu idea, pero yo tengo un rango de tiempo muy amplio y por ende necesito si o si poder hacer zoom a diferentes niveles.

Answer (score 0):

Investigando a fondo, pude averiguar que no es posible mostrar 2 ejes de X en un mismo componente "Navigator". Por ende tuve que buscar otra solución.

Lo que hice fue tomar los nuevos extremos al modificar el zoom del rango en el "Navigator" y setearselos al eje superior, de la siguiente manera:

```
xAxis: [{
  type: 'datetime',
  events: {
    afterSetExtremes() {
      let bottomAxis = this,
      topAxis = this.chart.xAxis[1],
      diferenciaMin = Math.abs(bottomAxis.dataMin - bottomAxis.min),
      diferenciaMax = Math.abs(bottomAxis.dataMax - bottomAxis.max);
      topAxis.setExtremes(topAxis.dataMin + diferenciaMin, topAxis.dataMax - diferenciaMax, true)
    }
  }
}, {
  type: 'datetime',
  opposite: true,
}],
```

La lógica es simple. Dejo tambien la documentación oficial de la función afterSetExtremes():
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes